# Angular2 FormGroup disabled field value

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form.
One field is disabled, so how do i get that value from the form in controller?
Writing the the FormGroup to console it doesnt display the disabled field at all, even tho it's displayed in the view.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the FormGroup's `getRawValue()` to include control values regardless of enable/disable state.

[More information in the API documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup/)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.yourForm.getRawValue().yourKey
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: Please see "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)"
and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.